# TextBoxSetting Validation not Working with <Telerik:RadTextBox> [ How Fix? ]

Tags: .net, asp.net, telerik

There are reports of this kind of problem in their own forum Telerik, and some comment saying it is not possible. That only works with InputManager  components. But in my case, I need to have both features, I need to use components from Telerik () with validations.

Some friends know me suggest some solution. Whether using Ajax or some other technology or method? Thanks for any help.

Note: I believe the people here will help me a lot more than the forum Telerick :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you think you will find more help here - the Telerik staff is quite responsive in their forums, I have not complaints. Anyway, RadTextBox should work Ok with asp client and server validation, check out [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/common/validation/defaultcs.aspx).

Dick